# How do I make a number quickly rise from zero when rendering a page in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Example of what I want: https://www.activate1m1b.org/

I want to include a section in my website that shows the number of people reached on the site, but I want the number to start at zero and quickly rise to the number I want (as shown in the example site). I am using React.js, and I'm not sure if this would be a CSS feature or something I would have to code in JS. Any ideas?

Comment: I went to the link and it is not showing a rising number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-countup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup):

```
<CountUp start={0} end={100} duration={2.5} delay={1} />
```

The example above will render a counter from `0` to `100` in `2.5` seconds after an initial delay of `1` second. Check [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup#installation) and [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/glennreyes/react-countup/tree/master/demo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview) for more about its props and usage.

Answer (score 2):

you can do with timeout function like this.

```
count = params => {
    let count = this.state.counter;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        counter: count + 1
      });
      if (this.state.counter === this.state.length) return;
      this.count();
    }, 100);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.count();
  }
```

here is the working demo :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-gu1z0?file=/src/index.js

Comment: this is good. but what if the length is very huge? it will take forever.

Comment: @ivp you have any alternative solution ?